# Transform an object to add new keys based on existing key-values

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I need to transform this object :

```
myObject  = {
"pageName": "home",
"dataExtract": "data1|data2=value2|data3=value3|data4=value4a,value4b,value4c"}
```

To this one:

```
myObject_mod = {
'pageName' : 'home',
'dataExtract' : {
    'data1'     : '',  //no value for 'data1'
    'data2'     : 'value2',
    'data3'     : 'value3',
    'data4' : {
        'data4key1'     :   'value4a',
        'data4key2'     :   'value4b',
        'data4key3'     :   'value4c'
    }
 }
```

I've started by taking the 'dataExtract' key, and split it by "|", so I get its values splited:

```
myObject.dataExtract.split("|");

(4) ["data1", "data2=value2", "data3=value3", "data4=value4a,value4b,value4c"]
```

How can I continue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to build up your result object for every entry in your data extract. The general form would be:

```
myArray.reduce((resultObject, entryString) => {
  // some logic here
  resultObject[key] = resultValue;
  return resultObject
}, {});
```

For example:

```js
array = {
  "pageName": "home",
  "dataExtract": "data1|data2=value2|data3=value3|data4=value4a,value4b,value4c"
};
array_mod = {
  pageName: array.pageName,
  dataExtract: array.dataExtract.split("|").reduce((obj, entry) => {
    // handle cases like data1
    if (entry.indexOf('=') === -1) {
      obj[entry] = '';
      return obj;
    }

    // handle cases like data2 and data3
    const [key, value] = entry.split('=', 2);
    if (value.indexOf(',') === -1) {
      obj[key] = value;
      return obj;
    }

    // handle cases like data4
    const values = value.split(',');
    obj[key] = values.reduce((o, v, i) => (o[`${key}key${i+1}`] = v, o), {});
    return obj;
  }, {})
};

console.log(array_mod);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of `Array.split()`, `Array.reduce()`, and destructuring, to break the string into keys and values, and rebuild as an object:

```js
const object = {
  "pageName": "home",
  "dataExtract": "data1|data2=value2|data3=value3|data4=value4a,value4b,value4c"
}

const result = {
  ...object,
  dataExtract: object.dataExtract.split('|')
    .reduce((r, kv) => {
      const [key, value = ''] = kv.split('=')
      
      r[key] = !value.includes(',') ? 
        value 
        :
        value.split(',').reduce((ra, val, i) => {
          ra[`${key}key${i + 1}`] = val;
          
          return ra;
        }, {})
      
      return r
    }, {})
}

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score -1):

An alternative to what was already posted, also using `String.split` and `Array.reduce`:

```js
const array = {
  "pageName": "home",
  "dataExtract": "data1|data2=value2|data3=value3|data4=value4a,value4b,value4c"
};

const array_mod = {
  pageName: array.pageName,
  
  dataExtract: array.dataExtract.split('|').reduce((r, cur) => {
    const [k, v = ''] = cur.split('=', 2);
    const vs = v.split(',');
    r[k] = vs.length > 1 ? vs.reduce((sr, scur, i) => (sr[`${k}key${i + 1}`] = scur, sr), {}) : v;
    return r;
  }, {})
};

console.log(array_mod);
```

With comments and more explicit variable names:

```js
const array = {
  "pageName": "home",
  "dataExtract": "data1|data2=value2|data3=value3|data4=value4a,value4b,value4c"
};

const array_mod = {
  pageName: array.pageName,
  
  // Split by | and build a key => value object from it
  dataExtract: array.dataExtract.split('|').reduce((data, entry) => {
    // Grab key (before `=`) and value (after `=`)
    const [key, value = ''] = entry.split('=', 2);
    // Grab subvalues (separated by `,`) if any
    const subValues = value.split(',');
    // If there are at least 2 subvalues, build a key => value object from them
    data[key] = subValues.length > 1 
      ? subValues.reduce((sub, subVal, i) => (sub[`${key}key${i + 1}`] = subVal, sub), {})
      // Otherwise return the value as string
      : value;
    return data;
  }, {})
};

console.log(array_mod);
```